# What is the purpose of $this->request->get['token'] in opencart customer login file?

Tags: php, opencart

Trying to understand the Opencart Customer login system. The `ControllerAccountLogin` class at `catalog>controller>account>login.php` file has a condition `if (!empty($this->request->get['token']))` (after the `// Login override for admin users`, comment) which got me stuck.

**ControllerAccountLogin** (this not the complete controller but just the part i need to understand)

```
class ControllerAccountLogin extends Controller {
    private $error = array();

    public function index() {
        $this->load->model('account/customer');

        // Login override for admin users
        if (!empty($this->request->get['token'])) {

            $this->event->trigger('pre.customer.login');

            $this->customer->logout();
            $this->cart->clear();

            unset($this->session->data['wishlist']);
            unset($this->session->data['payment_address']);
            unset($this->session->data['payment_method']);
            unset($this->session->data['payment_methods']);
            unset($this->session->data['shipping_address']);
            unset($this->session->data['shipping_method']);
            unset($this->session->data['shipping_methods']);
            unset($this->session->data['comment']);
            unset($this->session->data['order_id']);
            unset($this->session->data['coupon']);
            unset($this->session->data['reward']);
            unset($this->session->data['voucher']);
            unset($this->session->data['vouchers']);

            $customer_info = $this->model_account_customer->getCustomerByToken($this->request->get['token']);
```

What is this `$this->request->get['token']`, what does it do, where was this token set and how do I `var_dump` to see it's value?

Comment: Not familiar with OpenCart, but sounds like it's just your authentication token for admins. Basically, it just checks whether you're logged in as an admin or not. If you are, it logs you out and clears all of your data.

Comment: I can't fully remember but as far as I remember I think that this is the snippet that enables admins to impersonate customers, typically when you impersonate a customer, the related token is fetched from users tables, injected into the request object and then you will be redirected to the front end login page (this controller)

Comment: so basically I can log in through the customer login using my admin credentials?

Comment: @ObsidianAge, I logged in as the admin and in the new tab logged in as a customer ... my session wasn't unset. I am logged in as both an admin and a customer at the same time.

Comment: What is your OpenCart version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In OpenCart, the administrator can login to the customer account without having to enter the customer password.

In admin panel / sale /customer there is a link with a lock icon and "Login into store" title for each customer, it's calling this method: `sale/customer/login`:

**admin\controller\sale\customer.php**

```
public function login() {
    ...
    $token = md5(mt_rand());
    ...
    $this->response->redirect($store_info['url'] . 'index.php?route=account/login&token=' . $token);
    ...
}
```

[image]

Comment: @Mecom this is what I meant by "impersonating a customer"

Comment: @AbdoAdel, thank you ... I could not understand you earlier.